# Client is not paying for my work

Tags: legal, payment-terms, difficult-client, client-support, late-payment

I know it is very common problem that client doesn't pay for the work done. 
But in my case Client is not a company, he is an individual. I gave him support for his work. I already told him that he has to give advance payment but he didn't pay anything still I worked because it was my first project so I didn't want to loose it (I know i did mistake here itself). now, after completion of work, also he is not paying anything and giving silly excuses like, this month I don't have money etc etc. This guy is working in some US company on L1 visa. Is there anyway to get my money legally or just threaten him? or how can I handle him. I have tried everything, asked him a date on which he will transfer the money or discussing his problems, whatever I could do.But he is not even bothering.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clients who don't pay their invoices what are your options?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/842/clients-who-dont-pay-their-invoices-what-are-your-options)

Comment: also http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/is-there-any-way-i-can-attempt-to-recover-16k-from-a-client-who-doesnt-feel-it

Answer (score 2):

If you and he are located in different countries, your legal remedies are few and expensive. If this is your first freelance project, consider it a "learning experience" -

1. NEVER start work before a deposit is made up front with people you don't know.  (Especially people you "meet" on line.)
2. NEVER give the final product before receiving full payment

If the client doesn't agree with those terms, try using a third party system where your money is kept in escrow until the work is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any webservice like odesk or elance? If he did not load a milestone, you cannot do anything.

Are you in the same country and have signed the contract? If not in both cases, then you cannot do anything?

Did you send him your work? If you did, you made a mistake.

Now, we can say that this was a lesson for you. Never, never and never start work with the client who didn't either load a milestone or paid you an advance. Never think that this will be your only project and that you have to work it in spite of everything. You have to be patient and smart and good at what you do, and clients will start appearing like mushrooms after the rain :).